# What is the workflow to build with docker AND docker-compose?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-compose

I have [this repo](https://github.com/rm-rf-etc/node-rest-auth-arangodb), and `docker-compose up` will launch the project, create 2 containers (a DB and API), and everything works.

Now I want to build and deploy to Kubernetes. I try `docker-compose build` but it complains there's no Dockerfile. So I start writing a Dockerfile and then discover that [docker/Dockerfiles don't support loading ENV vars from an env_file or .env file](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/28617). What gives? How am I expected to build this image? Could somebody please enlighten me?

What is the intended workflow for building a docker image with the appropriate environment variables?

Comment: >>Rename .example-env to .env, this file sets ENV vars for both the API and docker-compose.<<
have you done this step?

Comment: Ya, I keep the example file for people who are new to the project. The readme tells them to rename it. I figured out a decent solution. Also, I think what the docker devs intend is that env vars be passed at runtime, hence why --env-file is only available for `docker run` and not `docker build`. I'll update and answer my own question, I'm pushing the changes just now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've updated the project on github, it now all works, and the readme documents how to run it.

I realized that env vars are considered runtime vars, which is why `--env-file` is an option for `docker run` and not `docker build`. This must also (I assume) be why `docker-compose.yml` has the `env_file` option, which I assume just passes the file to `docker build`. And in Kubernetes, I think these are passed in from a configmap. This is done so the image remains more portable; same project can be run with different vars passed in, no rebuild required.

Thanks [ignacio-millán](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9811836/ignacio-mill%C3%A1n) for the input.

Answer (score 0):

Those environment variables shouldn't be set at docker build step but at running the application on Kubernetes or docker-compose.

So:

Write a Dockerfile and place it at root folder. Something like this:

```
FROM node
COPY package.json .
RUN npm install
COPY . .
ENTRYPOINT ["npm", "start"]
```

Modify docker-compose.yaml. In the image field you must specify the name for the image to be built. It should be something like this:

```
image: YOUR-DOCKERHUB-USERNAME/node-rest-auth-arangodb
```

There is no need to set `user` and `working_dir`

Build the image with `docker-compose build` (you can also do this with docker build)

Now you can use `docker-compose up` to run your app locally, with the `.env` file

To deploy it on Kubernetes you need to publish your image in dockerhub (unless you run Kubernetes locally):

```
docker push YOUR-DOCKERHUB-USERNAME/node-rest-auth-arangodb
```

Finally, create a Kubernetes manifest. Sadly kubernetes doesn't support env files as docker-compose do, you'll need to manually set these variables in the manifest:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: platform-api
  labels:
    app: platform-api
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: platform-api
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: platform-api
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: platform-api
        image: YOUR-DOCKERHUB-USERNAME/node-rest-auth-arangodb
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
        env:
          - name: NODE_ENV
            value: develop

---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: platform-db
  labels:
    app: platform-db
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: platform-db
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: platform-db
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: arangodb
        image: YOUR-DOCKERHUB-USERNAME/node-rest-auth-arangodb
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8529
        env:
          - name: ARANGO_ROOT_PASSWORD
            value: localhost
```

Deploy it with `kubectl create`

Please note that this code is just indicative, I don't know exactly your user case. Find more information in docker-compose and kubernetes docs and tutorials. Good luck!